# preloader for part of content in current theme wp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, preloader

I need to show preloader only in 'content' div, but preloader hides entire page. Structure site:

1. Title
2. Menu
3. Content (here i need preloader)
4. Footer

I can't find, where i need insert my code of preloader...

```js
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
 
 $(window).load(function() {
 $(".cssload-loader").delay(1400).fadeOut();
 $(".preloader").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");
 })
```

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 107;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cssload-loader {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 34.284271247462px;
 height: 34.284271247462px;
 margin-left: -17.142135623731px;
 margin-top: -17.142135623731px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 animation-name: cssload-loader;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-loader;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-loader;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-loader;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-loader;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-duration: 2.8s;
  -o-animation-duration: 2.8s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 2.8s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.8s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2.8s;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side {
 display: block;
 width: 4px;
 height: 14px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.81);
 margin: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation-duration: 1.045s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.045s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.045s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.045s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.045s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: ease;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(1),
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(5) {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 animation-name: cssload-rotate0;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-rotate0;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-rotate0;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-rotate0;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-rotate0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(3),
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 animation-name: cssload-rotate90;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-rotate90;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-rotate90;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-rotate90;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-rotate90;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(2),
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 animation-name: cssload-rotate45;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-rotate45;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-rotate45;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-rotate45;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-rotate45;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(4),
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 animation-name: cssload-rotate135;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-rotate135;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-rotate135;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-rotate135;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-rotate135;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(1) {
 top: 17.142135623731px;
 left: 34.284271247462px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(2) {
 top: 29.213203431093px;
 left: 29.213203431093px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(3) {
 top: 34.284271247462px;
 left: 17.142135623731px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(4) {
 top: 29.213203431093px;
 left: 5.0710678163691px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(5) {
 top: 17.142135623731px;
 left: 0px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(6) {
 top: 5.0710678163691px;
 left: 5.0710678163691px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(7) {
 top: 0px;
 left: 17.142135623731px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}
.cssload-loader .cssload-side:nth-child(8) {
 top: 5.0710678163691px;
 left: 29.213203431093px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-top: -7px;
 animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate0 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 60% {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate0 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 60% {
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate0 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 60% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate0 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate0 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 60% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate90 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 60% {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate90 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 60% {
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate90 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 60% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate90 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate90 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 60% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
      transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate45 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 60% {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate45 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 60% {
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate45 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 60% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate45 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate45 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 60% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
      transform: rotate(225deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate135 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 60% {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate135 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 60% {
  -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate135 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 60% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate135 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 60% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate135 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 60% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
      transform: rotate(315deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-loader {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-loader {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-loader {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-loader {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-loader {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<?php 
get_header();
get_template_part('index', 'banner');
?>
<!-- Blog Full Width Section -->
<div class="blog-section">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
   <!--Blog Area-->
   <div class="<?php elitepress_post_layout_class(); ?>" >
   <?php get_template_part('content',''); ?>
   <?php comments_template('',true); ?>
   </div>
   <!--/Blog Area-->
   <div class="preloader" style="display: block;"> 
      <div class="cssload-loader" style="display: block;">
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
        <div class="cssload-side"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div>
   </div>
     </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<!-- /Blog Full Width Section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using a FontAwesome spinner. Colors used are for visualization only.

```js
$(".spinner").delay(1400).fadeOut();
```

```css
header,
nav,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.spinner i {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<div class="content">
  <div class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: i want my spinner (;